# I think it's worth reopening this question

Tags: discussion, support

This quesion here was recently closed as a duplicate:

- [double linking verb "be"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/double-linking-verb-be)

It was closed as a duplicate of this question here:

- [Present Simple vs Present Progressive](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63336/present-simple-vs-present-progressive)

The second question has an excellent answer addressing the difference between the present simple and the present continuous and how the idiom *be kind to somebody* repeesents an action.

The Original Poster in the first question here, however, seems to have a narrower focus, namely why do we need two *BE*s here? If you speak English, this question is difficult to appreciate. However, it is a reasonable question. In many languages a sentence such as *she is kind to me* would have NO verb *BE* at all.

The question of why we need two *BE*s in such a sentence is therefore pertinent and useful for other readers. Could we reopen this question please?

Comment: I agree. If anything, it's more a duplicate of questions such as these: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48415/i-am-hurting-in-the-meaning-of-i-am-hurt-why, http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124108/is-the-verb-hurt-v-intransitive-to-feel-painful-a-non-continuous-verb.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Not really, I don't think. The first one there is about the fact that *HURT* like the verb *BOIL* has a different meaning depending on whether it's transitive or intransitive. The second is about the fact that we don't normally use the continuous with stative verbs - but there are edge cases. So I don't think any of those are dupes of the other two! They're 3 different question!!!! :-)

Comment: Hmmm, are you sure? I understand that the OP asked why there's a second "be" verb, but this is actually not the issue. The issue is why the stative verb, "be," is using "-ing." Explained in this context, it should become clear to us that it's not actually a second "be" verb, but rather, that "is" and "being" are expressing the same idea in two different, but complementary ways. It's like when there's a sentence, "had had." The two "hads" are expressing the same thing, but since each is doing it in its own way, both are necessary.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang That's the issue for you, but not for them!

Comment: To be fair, none of it is an issue for me. But it is an issue for the OP because the OP is approaching the issue from the wrong angle. We need to help the OP to stop thinking of it as "double linking verb 'be'" and to start thinking of it as "linking verb 'be' and 'gerund 'be.'"

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang The participle *be* ***is*** the linking *be*, isn't it?! (But anyhow, that's pretty much what I put in my post - so we kind of agree).

Comment: Well, I would say that it merits re-opening so that it can be marked as a duplicate of the correct question, but either way, you're right, I do agree for it to be re-opened.

Comment: @Teacher Just so you know, we don't need to reopen it to change the duplicate. We can edit the list of duplicates now (SE added a new feature)

Comment: @ColleenV I thought that feature was only for users who single-handedly closed questions as dupes. The so-called *dupe hammer*, in this case wouldn't it  be up to the mods to change the "original/older" question?

Comment: +1 for new features. Thanks, @ColleenV.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought 10k+ users might be able to do it, but I'm not sure. Luckily, I know a moderator who would be willing to edit the question if the community found better options ;) I found the MSE discussion and you're right about the gold badge holders: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/

Comment: I saw that there were 4 votes to reopen, so I went ahead and cast the final one.